# Postfix allows own domains to be sent without asking for logins

Tags: email, postfix, authentication, sasl

Postfix issue,  (I asked this yesterday and manged to delete my own post instead of editing it  sorry for that)

I use Postfix+SASL

I got these settings in `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,check_client_access hash:/var/lib/pop-before-smtp/hosts,reject_unauth_destination
```

and on this server I have the domain  myrealdomain.com

now if I use a SMTP tester and use the domain  fakedomain.com as sender it gets blocked as it should 
BUT if I use myrealdomain.com the mail server just dont accept the email it also delivers it to whatever email I tell it to deliver.

now I want it to ALWAYS ask for login and passwd when someone try to SEND an email from my server no matter if it uses a domain hosted on the mailserver or not!

as it is now you can use my server to spam other people as long as you use a domain that hosted on the mail server.

`postconf -n` output:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024

debug_peer_level = 1
debug_peer_list =
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = localhost
myhostname = mail.myrealdomain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.0.0/16
myorigin = /etc/mailname
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps   $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps  $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps     $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps $transport_maps
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
sender_canonical_maps =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = mail.myrealdomain.com ESMTP  FrogSMTP powered by FrogLinux
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =   permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,check_client_access hash:/var/lib/pop-before-    smtp/hosts,reject_unauth_destination 
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf,     proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

Comment: Are you sure the smtp tester isn't in your `$mynetworks`?

Comment: yes i even tested to create a email act on a friend old XP pc in outlook and i could mail stright to anyone aslong as i used a domain hosted on the server
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.0.0/16   
that all i have in mynetworks

Comment: Try adding this to your main.cf  `smtpd_relay_restrictions =` `permit_mynetworks,` 
 `permit_sasl_authenticated,`
 `reject_unauth_destination`

Comment: ok i did some kernel mods and had to reboot the server now it blocks like it should do not ask me why couse i cant figure out wth is going on anyhow it works now so im not gonna touch it lol :)

Comment: I suggest trying to figure out what made it work if you want to be someone who knows what he's doing.

Answer (score 2):

Your [`smtpd_recipient_restrictions`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions) are not strict enough. If this machine is not a MX, but a [MSA/MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_submission_agent) then you'll probably want to end with `reject`.

Example MSA/MTA setting:
`smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject`

This will accept mail from authenticated users and the addresses listed in [`mynetworks`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mynetworks) and reject all other mail.